# Why Writing Self-modifying code is bad? Mips assembly language. How to do it?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

This problem is paraphrased from an earlier edition of P&H.

Consider the following code used to implement the instruction:

```
      foo $s0, $s1, $s2


mask:   .word 0xfffff83f
start:  lw    $t0,mask($zero)
        lw    $s0,shifter($zero)
        and   $s0,$s0,$t0
        andi  $s2,$s2,0x1f
        sll   $s2,$s2,6
        or    $s0,$s0,$s2
        sw    $s0, shifter($zero)
shifter:sll   $s0,$s1,0
```

Add meaningful comments to the code and write a paragraph describing how it works.  Why do you suppose that writing "self-modifying code" such as this is a bad idea (and often times not actually allowed)?

Explanatory Notes:

1. Labels are equivalent to immediates corresponding to the address that the OS will decide for them. For example, if the OS decides to start the program at 100010, mask is the immediate 100010.
2. You may assume that the program is loaded at an address whose upper 16 bits are 0s. This assumption is needed since MIPS immediates are 16-bits, and references to shifter/mask are immediates interpreted as the lower 16-bits of shifter/mask. You may also assume that shifter and mask both have a msb (bit 15) of 0 - this assumption is needed since offsets are sign-extended.
3. We have not covered the .word directive yet.  This is an assembler directive, which is essentially an instruction to the assembler (NOT an assembly language instruction).  In this case, it tells the assembler to reserve a word of memory initialized to 0xfffff83f.  Mask is the address of this word (just as start is the address of the word in memory containing the machine code for that lw instruction).

Comment: SMC is hard to get right, runs slow on pipelined CPUs especially with separate instruction and data caches (and requires explicit flushing on ISAs where they're not coherent, unlike x86), and requires the code to be in a writeable + executable page (making shellcode injection exploits easier).

Comment: could you describe the code and comment on it? please.

Comment: Please describe what is still unclear about the code after looking up the instructions in a MIPS instruction set reference and stepping through the code using pen and paper.

Comment: it looks like your whole question is from the P&H book; is that so?  if so, is your question "why is this bad?" and "how to do it?" from your question title?  if that is the case, those questions are far too broad for a good Stackoverflow question